# Selenium Server - how to run tests I've written (and converted into ruby-rspec)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, selenium-server

I have a large number of unit tests contained within a few Suites in the Selenium firefox IDE.

I've exported the individual tests to ruby/rspec and saved the results.
I've also exported the test suites (they basically `require` all the unit tests).

I've installed java and downloaded the seleniumk server itself and started it ok (port 4444):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar
Apr 30, 2013 11:46:11 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
11:46:11.505 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 23.7-b01
11:46:11.508 INFO - OS: Linux 3.2.0-40-generic-pae i386
11:46:11.521 INFO - v2.32.0, with Core v2.32.0. Built from revision 6c40c18
11:46:11.634 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
11:46:11.635 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
11:46:11.636 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
11:46:11.637 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
11:46:11.637 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
11:46:11.678 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@fa3f1b
11:46:11.679 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
11:46:11.684 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
```

So what do I do now to run the actual ruby-rspec tests that I exported from the IDE and saved on my (Ubuntu) machine?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at this [blog](http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/) and [this](http://testingbot.com/support/getting-started/rspec.html)

Comment: Yes.  Unfortunately this doesn't help as I need the tests to run outside the project but thank you.